Right way to use shared volume on kubernetes
I have a codemeter container. Inside this codemeter container there is a user matlab (1000) defined to run. Also this user is in sudo. The local volume folder has the owner 1000.
When I start the container localy:
docker run -it --rm --name cm --volume ~/data/docker:/tmp  xxx/mycmtest:latest

everything works fine. Codemeter starts and add the licenseserver to the searchlist.
If I run this now on kubernetes the image hangs. My deployment looks like:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    environment: development
    app: cm
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cm
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cm
    spec:             
      volumes:
        - emptyDir: {}
          name: shared-cm      
      initContainers:
          - name: example-c
            image: busybox:latest
            command: ["sh","-c","chown -R 1000:1000 /data && chmod 755 /data"]
            resources:
              limits:
                cpu: "1"
                memory: 1Gi
            volumeMounts:
              - name: shared-cm
                mountPath: /data
      containers:      
        - name: ml
          image: xxx/mycmtest:latest                 
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data
              name: shared-cm 

I tried with and without initcontainer, because the shared-cm folder was root:root. Why the same docker container do run local well but not inside a kubernetes pod?
I used emptyDir volume because I need to start a second container inside the pod and both container have to share data.
The codemeter binary is started with sudo /usr/sBin/CodeMeterLin inside the container. I think this is not started well in kubernetes
Any idea or hint?

Have you tried using securityContext in your deployment and set user id as 1000 like runAsUser: 1000 and runAsGroup: 1000. Refer to this official k8 security context document. You can set the user for the container as well.
